# Comparing Sets held in a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I've got the following which takes multiple lines of user input such as 'English Bob Luke' to store a Set in a Dictionary about which people speak which language. I've used a Dictionary to hold the multiple lines of input to create multiple Sets, but I now need to compare the difference between Sets to see if someone only speaks one language.

```
languages = {}
while True:
  info = input('Line: ').split()
  if info != []:
    languages[info[0]] = set(info[1:])
  else:
    break
```

I can print the sets using the code below, but it doesn't seem to really get me anywhere!

```
for tongue in languages:
  print(set(languages[tongue]))
```

Totally stuck - any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Here in example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
Line: English Tim Nicky James John Ben
Line: German Nicky Tim Tara
Line: Mandarin Tim John
Line: 
James is monolingual.
Tara is monolingual.
Ben is monolingual.
```

**SOLUTION**

Completely re-though my approach and ditched the Dictionary! :

```
english = input("Line: ").split()      
en_speakers = set(english[1:len(english)])

multi_speakers = set()

while True:
  language = input("Line: ").split()
  lan_speakers = language[1:len(language)] 
  if language == []:
    break
  else:
    multi_speakers |= set(lan_speakers)

monolinguals = en_speakers.difference(multi_speakers)

for person in monolinguals:
  print(person, 'is monolingual.')

if multi_speakers == en_speakers:
  print ('Everyone is multilingual!')
```

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: I've not got an error with the above code, I'm just not sure what to add to it to allow me to compare the difference between the sets held in the dictionary. I need to be able to print something like 'Luke is monolingual' if Luke appears in only one Set.

Comment: You shouldn't add a solution in the body of your question as a later edit. Rather, add it as a real solution and mark it as the answer. However, your solution is not correct, because it misses `Tara` from your example. That's because you're ignoring people who don't speak English by taking only the difference from the English set.

Comment: Fair shout. New round here - just thought a solution near the top would save future visitors a trawl! The exercise states that we should assume that everyone speaks English, hence my strategy to compare everything against the first line of input. Must be a mistake in the sample program text. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reverse the order of keys and values in your dictionary, because it makes the problem so much easier. So rather than storing per language the different users that speak it, just create a per user profile of all the languages that person speaks:

```
from collections import defaultdict

user_langs = defaultdict(list)

while True:
    info = map(lambda s: s.strip(), raw_input('Line: ').split())
    if info:
        for user in info[1:]:
            user_langs[user].append(info[0])
    else:
        break

for user in user_langs:
    if len(user_langs[user]) < 2:
        print("{} is monolingual.".format(user))
```

Comment: Nice way of turning it on its head! Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

`languages[toungue]` is already a set, you don't need to `set(languages[touge])`.
Also you don't need to loop the dictionary you can simply get those set from dictionary by `lanuages.values()`.

Not entirely sure what you want to achieve here though. At a wild guess, you may want the unique value from the languages values?

You can achieve this by updating values to a new set:

Change this:

```
for tongue in languages:
  print(set(languages[tongue]))
```

To this:

```
new_set = set()
for v in languages.values():
    new_set.update(v)

new_set # dummy lanugages
{'English', 'Japanese', 'whatever', 'yeah'}
```

#### Updated

To achieve what you want, you can use Counter and return the key if value == 1.

A more detailed explanation is that, under a `for/loop` you are going to compare 1 set to another set. But what you actually need,is to compare all sets, so I choose to use `c` to update all individual set values under a `for/loop`, and afterward do whatever you want out from that `c`. I use `Counter` here as what you want to count if anyone has only got 1 language.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()

for v in languages.values():
    c.update(v)

for k,v in c.iteritems():
    if v == 1:
        print k, " is monolingual"

Ben  is monolingual
James  is monolingual
Tara  is monolingual
```

---

The `c` looks like this:

```
c
Counter({'Tim': 3, 'Nicky': 2, 'John': 2, 'Ben': 1, 'James': 1, 'Tara': 1})
```

Comment: I just need to be able to look at the difference between the sets held in the dictionary. So for example, if based on what a user inputs, I end up with three sets in the dictionary that tell me which people speak three different languages, I need to be able to then compare the sets to see if someone is monolingual i.e. their name only appears on one set in the dictionary. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @Mathmos, it doesn't make sense to me, you get the info as a set already from the dictionary itself. what exactly do you want to compare? can you update OP to show a sample what your expected output is?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the help and patience btw!

Comment: @Mathmos, I have updated my answer to achieve what you want :)

Comment: Much appreciated for the help : )